# The if statement doesn't return anything TRUE even though it should

Tags: javascript, if-statement, multidimensional-array, google-apps-script, comparison

I am trying to compare values from columns from 2 sheets but it doesn't work. I'm new to this, i think it's the if statement because i tryed logging any possible variable and everything works.

```
function combineemail() {

var  source = SpreadsheetApp.getActive();
var  source_sheet = source.getSheetByName("Export1");
var  source2_sheet = source.getSheetByName("Sheet1");
var  target_sheet = source.getSheetByName("Merge1");
var  numRows = source_sheet.getLastRow() - 1;
var  source_range = source_sheet.getRange(2, 5, numRows, 1).getValues();
var  numRows2 = source2_sheet.getLastRow() - 1;
var  source2_range = source2_sheet.getRange(2, 2, numRows2, 1).getValues();
var c = "Merge"

for (var i = 0; i < numRows; i++){
for (var j = 0; j < numRows2; j++){
    if (source_range[i] == source2_range[j]) {
      Logger.log(source2_range[j]);
    }; 
};
};
```

};

Comment: A single column is still a two dimensional array. So you need two indices.

Comment: What are you comparing?

Comment: @Cooper, not sure what you mean, i'm new to this.

Comment: @TheMaster, email address

Comment: Since you are only getting 1 column it should be something like source_range[i][0] == source2_range[j][0]

Comment: Go to the debugger and single step through your program and take a look at what getValues returns. It’s a two dimensional array even if there’s only one column or one row it’s still a two dimensional array. Try [i][0].

Answer (score 0):

`getValues()` assign a multidimensional array (2D array) to `source_range` and `source2_range` . When you do `source_range[i] == source2_range[j]` your are comparing two arrays but on JavaScript this is complex.

If you are looking to compare cells values of two single column ranges then you should use

```
source_range[i][0] == source2_range[j][0]
```

- The first index corresponds to rows
- The second index corresponds to columns

Bear in mind that JavaScript indexes are `0` based while SpreadsheetApp row/column indexes are `1` based.
Reference

- [How to compare arrays in JavaScript?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/7837456/1595451)